# C++11 what happens when a function returns

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm wondering what happens when I have a function like this:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> stringmap;

stringmap merge (stringmap a,stringmap b) 
{
  stringmap temp(a); temp.insert(b.begin(),b.end()); return temp;
}
```

what happens when the function returns?

Is 'temp' copied to a temporary r-value before being destroyed (out-of-scope) and with C++11 possibly NRVO-ptimized (so the copy of 'temp' is directly written to the return destination slot)?

Comment: The copy is most likely elided via NRVO in C++03 *and* C++11.

Comment: It's either: a) moved if a move ctor is available or b) copied if the first does not work. And of course, (N)RVO can apply both times.

Comment: Since you are not needing a copy of `b`, the second parameter should be changed to `const stringmap& b`. For the first one, I'd recommend to move it to `temp`, i.e., `stringmap temp(std::move(a));`. That won't break the NRVO, so the return value is still optimized.

Comment: poor question. already had many similar questions on SO. always the same answer. boooooring.

Comment: I suppose not everyone knows everything

Comment: @ViniyoShouta that's not my problem with it. the problem is that it's not showing any research effort ...

Comment: For VS2012 debugging I can assure you that is a copy ctor call unless you do `return std::move(temp);` I know release mode (-O version) the one that matters but when it comes to returning containers, your debugging session hangs on a turtle's neck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing should be copied. There are two possibilities:

- `temp` is moved to an object in the caller's scope; or
- the move is elided, and `temp` becomes an alias for an object in the caller's scope. This is known as "return value optimisation".

Before 2011 (specifically, without move semantics), the first case would require a copy rather than a move. The second case was allowed in C++98 as well as 11.

Comment: It's true in the case of `std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string>` nothing is copied but in general there can be a copy if the return type is not movable.

Answer (score 5):

NRVO would mean that `temp` itself is constructed in the return value location. Without RVO, yes, `temp` is copied/moved from its location on the stack into the return value location prior to being destroyed.

Comment: In C++11, without RVO, it should be moved, not copied.

Answer (score 4):

This would typically, without any special rules, result in a copy from `temp` to the return value of the function. However, there are two rules in the standard that aim to improve this. The first is that the copy may be elided (12.8/31):

> in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cvunqualified type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the function’s return value

This is often known as named return value optimization (NRVO), a special case of [return value optimization (RVO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

The second is that, since this situation meets the above criterion for copy elision, it will first be considered as a move (12.8/32):

> When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be met save for the fact that the source object is a function parameter, and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue.

So the compiler will attempt the following steps:

- Does the class have a move constructor?

  - If so, either move it or elide the move.
  - If not, does the class have a copy constructor?

    - If so, either move it or elide the copy.
    - If not, we can't copy or move this object.

Note that the class has to have either a move or copy constructor for this to work, even if the move or copy is elided.